# TextSearchQuery not works in MailKit

Tags: mailkit

I use MailKit and IMAP Client. I want get messages if they have specified subject:

```
client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
var query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains("my_subject");
var uids = client.Inbox.Search(query);
if (!uids.Any())
    MessageBox.Show("Empty list!");
```

but all methods which returns `TextSearchQuery` (eg. `SubjectContains`, `BodyContains`, `FromContains`...) not works and I get MessageBox with empty list info. But if my query return `SearchQuery` eg.:

```
var query = SearchQuery.NotSeen;
```

or

```
var query = SearchQuery.NotFlagged;
```

it works correctly. Where is the problem? With chars encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I changed "_" char in subject with "+" (permissible in Base64, perhaps it matters).

Answer (score 0):

Different IMAP servers implement text matching differently. Some IMAP servers do a literal substring search while others tokenize the message text/subject text when the message arrives and keep a database of which messages contain which words.

Some IMAP servers decode the text (if it is encoded) and some do not.

Text-based searching is all completely dependent upon the IMAP server you are using.